# Прогресс загрузки Youtube-dl

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, youtube, qprogressbar

Создал загрузчик видео с **`YouTube`** с помощью *PyQt5* в ООП стиле с классами.

Добавил `progressbar` и хочу, чтобы при скачивании процент скачивания писался не только в консоль, но и в прогрессбар, соответственно его заполняя и обновляясь каждые `0.5` секунд.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from PyQt5 import *
import sys
import youtube_dl
from ytdl import *
import os
class downloader(QtCore.QThread):
    signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.link = None
    def run(self):
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({}) as ydl:
            ydl.download([self.link])

    def init_args(self, link):
        self.link = link
class gui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.dl_folder = None
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.start)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.get_folder)
        self.mythread = downloader()
    def start(self, d):
        if len(self.ui.lineEdit.text()) > 5:    
            if self.dl_folder != None:
                url = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
                self.mythread.init_args(url)
                self.mythread.start()
                self.ui.progressBar.setValue(None)
            else:
               QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(self, "Ошибка", "Вы не выбрали папку!")
        else:
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(self, "Ошибка", "Ссылка на видео не указана!")
    def get_folder(self):
        self.dl_folder = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'Выбрать папку для сохранения')
        try:
            os.chdir(self.dl_folder)
        except:
            pass
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = gui()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] (добавьте модуль, который содержит `Ui_MainWindow`). 
Расскажите что такое `youtube_dl` и `ytdl` и как вы их устанавливали. 
Имеется ли возможность получить данные о размере скачиваемого видео и о размере куска, который уже скачен ?
Какую ОС вы используете ?

Comment: os windows 10, youtube-dl библиотека позволяющая скачивать видео с ютуба. ytdl - название файла в котором дизайн всего окна, в моем вопросе указан функционал. о скачивании. в консоли при скачивании пишется название файла, сколько времени осталось , вес файла/сколько скачалось, и проценты. мне необходимо закидывать в прогрессбар последнее.

Answer (score 1):

Метод загрузки `youtube_dl` занимает много времени и должны запускаться в дополнительном потоке.

`youtube_dl` предоставляет два средства информации: `hooks` и `logger`.
Эти носители выполняются в том же потоке, что и метод загрузки,
поэтому к ним следует обращаться не напрямую, а через сигналы.

**main.py**

```
import os
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

from qyoutubedl import QLogger, QHook, QYoutubeDL

# hurry.filesize простая библиотека Python, которая может принимать количество байтов 
# и возвращать удобочитаемую строку с указанием размера в килобайтах(K), мегабайтах(M) и т.д.
from hurry.filesize import size                 # pip install hurry.filesize


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.url_le = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.download_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tr("Download"))
        self.download_btn.clicked.connect(self.download)
        self.progress_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.progress_lbl.setFixedWidth(80)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()                      
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Get folder')      
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.get_folder)
        
        self.download_pgb = QtWidgets.QProgressBar()
        self.log_edit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(readOnly=True)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        lay = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(central_widget)
        lay.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tr("url:")))
        lay.addWidget(self.url_le, 0, 1)
        lay.addWidget(self.download_btn, 0, 2)
        lay.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tr("папка для Save:")), 1, 0)        
        lay.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 1, 1)
        lay.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 2)
        lay.addWidget(self.progress_lbl, 2, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.download_pgb, 2, 1, 1, 2)
        lay.addWidget(self.log_edit, 3, 1, 1, 2)
        self.progress_lbl.hide()

        self.downloader = QYoutubeDL()
        self.url_le.setText("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZSMDjea93Qw")

    def download(self):
        if not self.lineEdit.text():
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(self, "Ошибка", "Вы не выбрали папку!")
            return    
        if len(self.url_le.text()) < 10:
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(self, "Ошибка", "Ссылка на видео указана \n неправильно!")
            return
            
        os.chdir(self.lineEdit.text())
        qhook = QHook()
        qlogger = QLogger()
        url = self.url_le.text()
        
        options = {
            "format": "bestvideo[height=144]+bestaudio/best",
            "noplaylist": True,
            "postprocessors": [{"key": "FFmpegMetadata"}],
            "noprogress": True,
            "logger": qlogger,
            "progress_hooks": [qhook],
        }
        self.downloader.download([url], options)
        qhook.infoChanged.connect(self.handle_info_changed)
        qlogger.messageChanged.connect(self.log_edit.appendPlainText)

        self.download_pgb.setRange(0, 1)

    def handle_info_changed(self, d):
        if d["status"] == "downloading":
            self.progress_lbl.show()
            total = d["total_bytes"]
            downloaded = d["downloaded_bytes"]
            self.progress_lbl.setText("{} of {}".format(size(downloaded), size(total)))
            self.download_pgb.setMaximum(total)
            self.download_pgb.setValue(downloaded)

    def get_folder(self):
        self.dl_folder = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(
            self, 'Выбрать папку для сохранения')
        if self.dl_folder:
            self.lineEdit.setText(self.dl_folder)
        else: self.lineEdit.clear()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**qyoutubedl.py**

```
import threading
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import youtube_dl                                        #  pip install youtube_dl


class QLogger(QtCore.QObject):
    messageChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def debug(self, msg):
        self.messageChanged.emit(msg)

    def warning(self, msg):
        self.messageChanged.emit(msg)

    def error(self, msg):
        self.messageChanged.emit(msg)


class QHook(QtCore.QObject):
    infoChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(dict)

    def __call__(self, d):
        self.infoChanged.emit(d.copy())


class QYoutubeDL(QtCore.QObject):
    def download(self, urls, options):
        threading.Thread(
            target=self._execute, args=(urls, options), daemon=True
        ).start()

    def _execute(self, urls, options):
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(options) as ydl:
            ydl.download(urls)
        for hook in options.get("progress_hooks", []):
            if isinstance(hook, QHook):
                hook.deleteLater()
        logger = options.get("logger")
        if isinstance(logger, QLogger):
            logger.deleteLater()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable выдает такую ошибку на строке "if d["status"] == "downloading":"