# Остановить скачивание видео при нажатии кнопки

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Приложение для скачивания видео. 
В одной функции я проверяю все значение и добавляю `MessageBox` с ошибками и запускаю функцию скачивания видео.

Скачивание проходит с помощью **`youtube-dl`**.

Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии кнопки скачивание останавливалось.

```
import youtube_dl
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import os


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(600, 500)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(600, 500))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1200, 1000))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../../../../../Downloads/youtube.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(62, 62, 62);\n"
"background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30);")
        MainWindow.setTabShape(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.Triangular)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.url_line = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.url_line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 500, 30))
        self.url_line.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.DefaultContextMenu)
        self.url_line.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.url_line.setStyleSheet("font: 12pt \"Times New Roman\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 0, 0);\n"
"border: 1px solid red;")
        self.url_line.setText("")
        self.url_line.setReadOnly(False)
        self.url_line.setCursorMoveStyle(QtCore.Qt.LogicalMoveStyle)
        self.url_line.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.url_line.setObjectName("url_line")
        self.path_line = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.path_line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 80, 425, 30))
        self.path_line.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 0, 0);\n"
"font: 12pt \"Times New Roman\";\n"
"border: 1px solid red;")
        self.path_line.setText("")
        self.path_line.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.path_line.setObjectName("path_line")
        self.quality_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.quality_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 130, 111, 25))
        self.quality_label.setStyleSheet("font: 10pt \"Times New Roman\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.quality_label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.quality_label.setObjectName("quality_label")
        self.quality_box = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.quality_box.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 130, 251, 23))
        self.quality_box.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 0, 0);\n"
"font: 10pt \"Times New Roman\";")
        self.quality_box.setEditable(False)
        self.quality_box.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QComboBox.AdjustToContents)
        self.quality_box.setObjectName("quality_box")
        self.quality_box.addItem("")
        self.download_but = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.download_but.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(225, 350, 150, 28))
        self.download_but.setStyleSheet("font: 75 12pt \"Times New Roman\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.download_but.setObjectName("download_but")
        self.path_but = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.path_but.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 80, 60, 30))
        self.path_but.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../../../рабочий стол обои/Find.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.path_but.setIcon(icon1)
        self.path_but.setObjectName("path_but")
        self.info_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.info_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 460, 600, 20))
        self.info_label.setStyleSheet("font: 75 12pt \"Times New Roman\";")
        self.info_label.setText("")
        self.info_label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.info_label.setObjectName("info_label")
        self.download = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.download.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 400, 550, 25))
        self.download.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 0, 0);\n"
"font: 10pt \"Times New Roman\";")
        self.download.setProperty("value", 24)
        self.download.setObjectName("download")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Youtube downloader"))
        self.url_line.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вставьте URL ссылку на видео"))
        self.path_line.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выберите папку для видео"))
        self.quality_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Качество видео"))
        self.quality_box.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Только аудио"))
        self.download_but.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Скачать"))
        self.path_but.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Путь"))
        self.download_but.clicked.connect(self.download_video)
        self.path_but.clicked.connect(self.get_folder)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.url_flag = False
        self.fol_flag = False
        self.setupUi(self)


    def get_video(self):
        if len(self.url_line.text()) > 5:
            self.url = self.url_line.text()
            self.url_flag = True


    def download_video(self):
        if self.download_but.text() == 'Скачать':
            self.get_video()
            if self.url_flag:
                if self.fol_flag:
                    self.run(True)
                    self.download_but.setText('Отмена')
                else:
                    QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Ошибка', 'Вы не указали папку')
            else:
                QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Ошибка', "Вы не указали URL ссылку!")
        else:
            self.run(False)
            self.download_but.setText('Скачать')
            # ?????????????7

    def get_folder(self):
        self.dow_fol = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Выберите папку для видео")
        if self.dow_fol != '':
            self.fol_flag = True
            self.path_line.setText(str(self.dow_fol))
            os.chdir(self.dow_fol)

    def locker(self, lock_val):
        buttons = [self.path_but, self.url_line, self.quality_box, self.path_line]
        for i in buttons:
            i.setDisabled(lock_val)

    def run(self, run_value):
        if run_value:
            with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({}) as ydl:
                ydl.download([self.url])
                self.locker(True)
        else:
            break
            # ?????

    def quality(self):
        pass

    def progressbar(self):
        pass

    def label_info(self):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Я искал какую-нибудь функцию в самом **`yotube-dl`** но ничего не нашел.

Comment: скажите пожалуйста, ваш пример действительно начинает скачивать какое-то видео ?

Comment: ну если убрать этот код с отменой то да все работает

Comment: но нужно понимать что еще сырой и даже наполовину не готов

Comment: а вот этот пример у вас работает ? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1200917/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b8-youtube-dl/1201592#1201592

Comment: Mr.White вы проверили то что я написал выше?