# Как скачать видео ютуб на питон?

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, youtube-dl

Как скачать видео ютубе на питон? 
Я пытался скачать видео через *pytube*, *youtube_dl* - либо ошибка или было что видео с звуком, но без картинки или просто видео файл без нечего (разные коды)

**`os linux ubuntu 20.04`**. Буду благодарен за ответ.

Comment: `youtube_dl` раньше вроде работал, а сейчас такая-же фигня...

Comment: У меня версия `youtube_dl от 2021.6.6` https://pypi.org/project/youtube_dl/2021.6.6/ - все работает --> https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1200917/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b8-youtube-dl/1201592#1201592

Answer (score 4):

```
from pytube import YouTube

yt = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o5wC0QqqN1c') #ссылка на видео.
# yt.stream показывает какое видео ты можешь скачать 
# (mp4(720) + audio или только mp4(1080) без звука). 
# Сейчас стоит фильтр по mp4.
print(yt.streams.filter(file_extension='mp4')) 
stream = yt.streams.get_by_itag(22) #выбираем по тегу, в каком формате будем скачивать.
stream.download() #загружаем видео.
```

Answer (score 1):

Советую перейти форк `youtube-dl` - `yt-dlp`. Синтаксис полностью идентичен `youtube-dl`. К тому же, разработчики `youtube-dl` бросили проект и сказали всем перейти на `yt-dlp`. Так же у него немного больше функций, больше поддерживаемых сайтов для загрузки и больше скорость.

```py
import yt_dlp

def download(link, name='%(title)s'):
    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestvideo+bestaudio/best', #берем самое лучшее качество видео и фото
        'outtmpl': '{}.%(ext)s'.format(name), #наше выбраное имя, если его не было, то стандартное - название видео на самом сайте
    }
    with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        info_dict = ydl.extract_info(link, download=True)
        downloaded_file_path = ydl.prepare_filename(info_dict)
    print(f"Видео {downloaded_file_path} успешно загружено!")
    return downloaded_file_path


print(download('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uHgt8giw1LY', 'Привет!'))
```

Вы можете ознакомиться с документацией [здесь](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp#embedding-yt-dlp)

P.S. Возможно, я немного перегнул палку. Без возвращения пути и функции можно облегчить код до:

```py
import yt_dlp
ydl_opts = {'format': 'bestvideo+bestaudio/best'}
URLS = ['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uHgt8giw1LY']
with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(URLS)
```