# Написать код, чтобы интерфейс QtDesigner функционировал

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

Нужно чтобы при нажатии кнопки скачать видео с ютуба, началось скачивание видео по заданной ссылке. При нажатии кнопки выбрать папку, можно было выбрать папку, куда сохранять скачанные видео

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(681, 451)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 300, 651, 31))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.plainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 651, 281))
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 350, 651, 31))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("pushButton{\n"
"color:red;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 400, 651, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Скачать видео"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбрать место для сохранения"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: А какая тут проблема? Скопировал ваш код и запустил без проблем: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rUDX.png

Comment: нужно чтобы работали кнопки

Comment: У вас уже есть пример этого из прошлого вопроса. Для функционирования кнопок нужно к их сигналам подключать методы: `self.ui.pushbutton.clicked.connect(self.get_folder)`, тут clicked это сигнал

Comment: можете сделать, чтобы все работало?

Comment: Сначала опишите (в вопросе, не в комментарии) что пытались сделать, на каком моменте споткнулись, так будет понятно какая помощь нужна :)

Comment: все, написал проблему

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1200917 ?