# Progress bar в pytube

Tags: python, progress-bar, pytube

Подскажите, я качаю видео через библиотеку pytube. Найдены способы отображения индикатора выполнения. Что я делаю не так.

Код правильно загружает видео с YouTube, но я просто тупо смотрю на командную строку, ожидая завершения. Я хочу знать, сколько видео загружается с течением времени. Но я получаю сообщение об ошибке:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\programming\PycharmProjects\youtube_download_list\main_progress_bar.py", line 93, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\programming\PycharmProjects\youtube_download_list\main_progress_bar.py", line 89, in main
    download_video()
  File "D:\programming\PycharmProjects\youtube_download_list\main_progress_bar.py", line 63, in download_video
    x = v.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4', resolution=res).first().download()
  File "D:\programming\PycharmProjects\youtube_download_list\venvYoutubeList\lib\site-packages\pytube\streams.py", line 260, in download
    self.on_progress(chunk, fh, bytes_remaining)
  File "D:\programming\PycharmProjects\youtube_download_list\venvYoutubeList\lib\site-packages\pytube\streams.py", line 337, in on_progress
    self._monostate.on_progress(self, chunk, bytes_remaining)
  File "D:\programming\PycharmProjects\youtube_download_list\main_progress_bar.py", line 43, in on_progress
    display_progress_bar(bytes_received, filesize)
  File "D:\programming\PycharmProjects\youtube_download_list\main_progress_bar.py", line 28, in display_progress_bar
    _, columns = get_terminal_size()
  File "D:\programming\PycharmProjects\youtube_download_list\main_progress_bar.py", line 23, in get_terminal_size
    rows, columns = os.popen('stty size', 'r').read().split()
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

Мой код:

````py
import os
import sys
from pytube import Playlist
from pytube import YouTube
import random
import time
from urllib.error import HTTPError

p = Playlist('youtube url')
extensions = ['720p', '720p60', '480p', '360p']


def copy_urls_in_txt():
    with open('playlist_url.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        for element in p:
            file.write(element)
            file.write('\n')
        file.close()


def get_terminal_size():
    """Return the terminal size in rows and columns."""
    rows, columns = os.popen('stty size', 'r').read().split()
    return int(rows), int(columns)


def display_progress_bar(bytes_received, filesize, ch='█', scale=0.55):
    _, columns = get_terminal_size()
    max_width = int(columns * scale)

    filled = int(round(max_width * bytes_received / float(filesize)))
    remaining = max_width - filled
    bar = ch * filled + ' ' * remaining
    percent = round(100.0 * bytes_received / float(filesize), 1)
    text = ' ↳ |{bar}| {percent}%\r'.format(bar=bar, percent=percent)
    sys.stdout.write(text)
    sys.stdout.flush()


def on_progress(stream, chunk, bytes_remaining):
    filesize = stream.filesize
    bytes_received = filesize - bytes_remaining
    display_progress_bar(bytes_received, filesize)


def download_video():
    with open('playlist_url.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        count = 1
        while True:
            line = file.readline()
            if not line:
                break

            v = YouTube(url=line, on_progress_callback=on_progress)

            for res in extensions:
                video_title = v.title
                try:
                    # print(res)
                    print(f"Trying to download {count}# {video_title} by {res}...")
                    x = v.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4', resolution=res).first().download()
                    success = f"{count}# {video_title} - {res} was download successfully"
                    print(success)
                    count += 1
                    time.sleep(random.randrange(10, 15))
                    break
                except AttributeError as ater:
                    print(f"Can't download {count}# {video_title} - {res}... AttrError string 31")
                    print(ater)
                    continue
                except HTTPError as httper:
                    print(f"Can't download {count}# {video_title} - {res}... HttpError string 35")
                    print(httper)
                    continue
                except TimeoutError:
                    print(TimeoutError)
                    print("Sleep on 30-50")
                    time.sleep(random.randrange(30, 50))
                except Exception as ex:
                    print(f"Hz che za ex string 40\n{ex}")
                    time.sleep(random.randrange(30, 50))
                    continue


def main():
    # copy_urls_in_txt()
    download_video()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()```
````

Comment: Ну видимо команда `stty size` ничего не вернула в `stdout`. Может она ошибку выдаёт? Разбирайтесь с этим. Операционка какая у вас? Под линуксом выдаёт что-то, а под виндой у меня ругается.

Comment: @CrazyElf у меня винда

Comment: Ну и вот. Попробуйте в командной строке дать команду `stty size` и посмотрите результат. Чудес не бывает, если у вас будет ошибка, то и `os.popen('stty size', 'r')` даст ошибку.

Comment: как вариант https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1200917/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b8-youtube-dl/1201592#1201592

Comment: @S.Nick вариант хороший, спасибо за подсказку. Но хотел с pytube до конца разобраться, но пока что-то завис

Comment: @CrazyElf единственное понял что ```stty size``` это linux команда, которая, является достаточно универсальной в linux. Она открывает команду ```stty size``` как файл, «читает» из него и использует простое разбиение строки для разделения координат. Пока не нашёл каким образом это можно интерпретировать в Windows

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
from pytube.cli import on_progress
....
object = (YouTube(link, on_progress_callback=on_progress))
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! 1. пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]. 2. переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык